# Serialize class to XML results in "invalid XML document" error

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have an object of the following class:

```
public class Root
{
    [XmlElement]
    public BOMItems[] Row { get; set; }
}
public class BOMItems
{
    [XmlElement("ITEMNO")]
    public string ITEMNO { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("USED")]
    public string USED { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("PARTSOURCE")]
    public string PARTSOURCE { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("QTY")]
    public string QTY { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to serialize it to an `XDocument` with this method:

```
public XDocument TransformClassToXMLBOM(Root rt)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
    var sww = new StringWriter();
    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto;
    var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww, settings);

    serializer.Serialize(writer, rt);

    var doc = new XDocument( 
                    new XElement("Row",
                        new XElement("ITEMNO"),
                        new XElement("USED"),
                        new XElement("PARTSOURCE"),
                        new XElement("QTY")));                                           
    doc.Save(writer);
    return doc;
}
```

I have even tried with an extra element inserted before `new XElement("Row",` like this:

```
var doc = new XDocument( 
               new XElement("Root",
                    new XElement("Row",...
```

I always get the error below on this line `doc.Save(writer);`:

> Token StartDocument in state EndRootElement would result in an
>   invalid XML document. Make sure that the ConformanceLevel setting is
>   set to ConformanceLevel.Fragment or ConformanceLevel.Auto if you want
>   to write an XML fragment.

At first I thought I might be missing an XElement or have something misspelled, but I can't find any mistakes.  I don't know how to look at the values in `writer` to check the results, so I have no idea how to find a solution on this.

I would like to end with something like this:

```
<Root>
  <Row>
    <ITEMNO>1</ITEMNO>
    <USED>Y</USED>
    <PARTSOURCE>BUY</PARTSOURCE>
    <QTY>10</QTY>
  </Row>
</Root>
```

How do I find the cause of the problem?  What is the correct way to accomplish my desired results?

Comment: what is that you want to achieve? can you clearly state your output ?

Comment: I want the Root object converted to an XML string

Comment: see my below answer.. is that what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out Xml Serializable Generic Dictionary
http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2006/05/03/444961.aspx
You can do nearly the same for your case.

Upd
Then you can serialize yor class using standart serializartion like this

```
    public static string SerializeObjectToXml<T>(T obj)
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8);

        xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, obj);
        memoryStream = (MemoryStream)xmlTextWriter.BaseStream;

        string xmlString = ByteArrayToStringUtf8(memoryStream.ToArray());

        xmlTextWriter.Close();
        memoryStream.Close();
        memoryStream.Dispose();

        return xmlString;
    }
```

upd2

```
    public static string ByteArrayToStringUtf8(byte[] value)
    {
        UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        return encoding.GetString(value);
    }
```

upd3

A more cleare way:

```
[Serializable]
public class Root
{
    [XmlElement("ITEMS")]
    public BOMItem[] Row { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class BOMItem
{
    [XmlElement("ITEMNO")]
    public string ITEMNO { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("USED")]
    public string USED { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("PARTSOURCE")]
    public string PARTSOURCE { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("QTY")]
    public string QTY { get; set; }
}
```

so you can get your xml like this:

```
        Root r1 = new Root();
        r1.Row = new BOMItem[2];
        r1.Row[0] = new BOMItem {ITEMNO = "1", PARTSOURCE = "11", QTY = "111", USED = "1111"};
        r1.Row[1] = new BOMItem { ITEMNO = "2", PARTSOURCE = "22", QTY = "222", USED = "2222" };
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Serialization result: {0}", SerializeObjectToXml(r1)));
```

Comment: How does that help?  I don't see how it demonstrates how to serialize a custom class.

Comment: Implemet ISerializable interface in your class and you'll be fine

Comment: Where do you get/define `ByteArrayToStringUtf8`?

Comment: Update 3 looks more nicely if you are not going to use something extraordinary.